# postgis: scaling / optimization of shortest distance between two geometries (seeking recommendations)

Tags: postgis, spatial-index, points-to-line

I have two tables in postgis:

- one with 1B rows containing points (POINT, 4326)::geometry
- the other, with 250k rows containing linestrings also in 4326
- Both tables have a GIST index.

I am trying to construct a query that looks at the entire combined geometry of all points and linestrings and tells me which points are nearest the linestrings (I don't need exact distance, closeness is fine).

My question is how to restructure / optimize the approach so that if I expand the size of geography I'm evaluating, the query will also scale efficiently (a return in minutes, few hours are fine...currently it takes days to run a full US query).

If I do the below query with a very small bounding box (ST_MakeEnvelope), I get results very quickly (less than 1sec).

```
SELECT id, lat, long, to_timestamp(unix_date) 

FROM point_data JOIN linestring_data on 

    ST_Intersects(linestring_data.wkb_geometry, ST_Buffer(point_data.geom, 0.0003)::geometry) 

WHERE geom && ST_MakeEnvelope(-75.188867,40.983303,-75.180389,40.989025, 4326);
```

Here is the query plan excluding WHERE (i.e. will query all points -- what I would like to do):

```
    Gather  (cost=1000.28..10429611075.47 rows=13454214512 width=64)
       Workers Planned: 2
       ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..9084188624.27 rows=5605922713 width=64)
             ->  Parallel Seq Scan on point_data  (cost=0.00..54331353.71 rows=715436671 width=96)
             ->  Index Scan using test_wkb_geometry_geom_idx on linestring_data  (cost=0.28..12.61 rows=1 width=425)
                   Index Cond: (wkb_geometry && st_buffer(point_data.geom, '0.0003'::double precision))
                   Filter: _st_intersects(wkb_geometry, st_buffer(point_data.geom, '0.0003'::double precision))
```

I've tried below as a way to limit the number of points in the form of a buffer around the entire linestring geometry,

```
SELECT  distinct on (id) id, lat, long, unix_date, 
    ST_Distance(point_data.geom, linestring_data.wkb_geometry) 

FROM point_data JOIN linestring_data on 
    ST_Intersects(linestring_data.wkb_geometry, ST_Buffer(point_data.geom, 
        0.0003)::geometry) 

WHERE geom && 
    (SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_Collect(wkb_geometry), 0.0003) 
         FROM linestring_data);
```

Here is the query plan from explain:

```
    Unique  (cost=3107502.58..3114229.70 rows=141065 width=72)
    InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=1554.84..1554.85 rows=1 width=32)
       ->  Seq Scan on linestring_data linestring_data_1  (cost=0.00..1496.07 rows=23507 width=425)
    ->  Sort  (cost=3105947.73..3109311.29 rows=1345423 width=72)
     Sort Key: point_data.ad_id
     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5811.55..2913801.67 rows=1345423 width=72)
           ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on point_data  (cost=5811.27..662541.58 rows=171705 width=96)
                 Recheck Cond: (geom && $0)
                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on geom_idx  (cost=0.00..5768.34 rows=171705 width=0)
                       Index Cond: (geom && $0)
           ->  Index Scan using test_wkb_geometry_geom_idx on linestring_data  (cost=0.28..12.61 rows=1 width=425)
                 Index Cond: (wkb_geometry && st_buffer(point_data.geom, '0.0003'::double precision))
                 Filter: _st_intersects(wkb_geometry, st_buffer(point_data.geom, '0.0003'::double precision))
```

Questions:

- Is there a more efficient way to construct indexes so these queries run more efficiently?
- Is there a better way to construct the queries?

Update:

I decided to simplify by using bounding boxes rather than buffer.  Here is the updated query:

```
    spatial=# explain SELECT  distinct on (id) id, lat, long, unix_date,
    spatial-#     ST_Distance(point_data.geom, linestring_data.wkb_geometry)
    spatial-#
    spatial-# FROM point_data JOIN linestring_data on
    spatial-#     ST_Intersects(linestring_data.wkb_geometry, ST_Expand(point_data.geom,
    spatial(#         0.0003))
    spatial-#
    spatial-# WHERE geom &&
    spatial-#     (SELECT ST_Envelope(wkb_geometry)
    spatial(#          FROM linestring_data)
    spatial-# ;
                                                        QUERY PLAN
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Unique  (cost=3107502.57..3114229.68 rows=141065 width=72)
       InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
         ->  Seq Scan on linestring_data linestring_data_1  (cost=0.00..1554.84 rows=23507 width=32)
       ->  Sort  (cost=3105947.73..3109311.29 rows=1345423 width=72)
             Sort Key: point_data.ad_id
             ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5811.55..2913801.67 rows=1345423 width=72)
                   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on point_data  (cost=5811.27..662541.58 rows=171705 width=96)
                         Recheck Cond: (geom && $0)
                         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on geom_idx  (cost=0.00..5768.34 rows=171705 width=0)
                               Index Cond: (geom && $0)
                   ->  Index Scan using test_wkb_geometry_geom_idx on linestring_data  (cost=0.28..12.61 rows=1 width=425)
                         Index Cond: (wkb_geometry && st_expand(point_data.geom, '0.0003'::double precision))
                         Filter: _st_intersects(wkb_geometry, st_expand(point_data.geom, '0.0003'::double precision))
    (13 rows)
```

Seems like it may have made an improvement?

Comment: in other words: you want to find the nearest linestring to each point?

Comment: vice versa - I want the result to be all the points that are nearest to the linestrings.

Comment: okay, and by a threshold then I take it (assuming from your use of buffers)? or do you want something like the top ten? because, if you want to uniquely reference *every* point to one distinct linestring, you´d want to go the other way

Comment: After thinking about your question on buffers, I realized that for a given linestring, buffers is going to create thousands of points that have to be evalauted.   So I decided to simplify to an envelope.  See updated question above.

Comment: Yes, I am going to try your first approach.  I'm currently converting geometry to geography and adding indexes.  The linestring table took 1 second to convert, the point data is probably going to take a few hours.  I'll let you know how it goes once I have everything set up.  Thanks again for sharing your recommendations.

Comment: Did you get results? I just saw the infos you tried to edit into my answer (better use comments instead or edit your question), you don´t need ST_Expand! converting the tables geometries to geography type has advantages only for certain scenarios (e.g. where precise distance measurements are the main intention). for most other cases, a simple cast would do the job.

Comment: Hi - yes my phone put me into editing the answer and I didnt realize it until I submitted.  After numerous days (5? I think) the query didn't finish and I decided it was not going to be efficient to go about trying to run the query on the entire database.  This is on a t2.large instance with no other users.  I've since divided the US in 30km X 30km tiles and then limit my queries with the geography of the tile.  If you think of any other way to do this, I would be grateful.  For now, the tile approach is very fast to return but not the most ideal to maintain.

Comment: I can't really follow anymore...what query did you run? If the above scenario stands (finding all points that are within a defined distance of your linestrings), just run my first approach on the initial tables (maybe add `pt.geom` to the `SELECT` list to actually get geometries). also, in any case, run `ANALYZE point_data` first to update the table stats so the planner avoids bitmap scans! if you updated your tables to *geography*, create new indexes and the run the analyze command!

Answer (score 2):

**Some initial notes:**

- using geographic CRS is a tricky business for anything distance
  related; a degree will not represent the same surface distance at
  different latitudes. You´d want to either use a projected CRS or cast to `geography` type for the implicit distance measurements
- in terms of performance, using buffers is generally a bad idea for proximity search (I think there´s even a hint at using [`ST_DWithin`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) instead on the doc page for `ST_Buffer` - [yes](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html))

**Two different approaches:**

You can get a list of all *POINT*s that are within a threshold around a *LINESTRING*, as you tried in your queries by using a buffer; this will produce duplicates for *POINT*s found in thresholds around multiple *LINESTRING*s (use `DISTINCT ON (pt.id)` as you did above, but the resulting POINT then is somewhat random) and exclude *POINT*s not in any of the thresholds (I included the *ln.id* to have a reference to the *LINESTRING* each *POINT* was found around):

```
SELECT pt.id AS point_id,
       ln.id AS line_id,
       pt.lat,
       pt.long,
       pt.to_timestamp(unix_date) AS date
FROM point_data AS pt
JOIN linestring_data AS ln
  ON ST_DWithin(ln.wkb_geometry, pt.geom, <distance_in_CRS_units>);
```

Or you can assign the nearest *LINESTRING* to each *POINT*; this effectively divides **all** *POINT*s into 'clusters' of their nearest *LINESTRING*, but will be slower:

```
SELECT pt.id AS point_id,
       ln.id AS line_id,
       pt.lat,
       pt.long,
       pt.to_timestamp(unix_date) AS date
FROM point_data AS pt
JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT id
    FROM linestring_data
    ORDER BY pt.geom <#> linestring_data.wkb_geometry
    LIMIT 1
) AS ln
ON true;
```

Both queries are optimized to utilize the index: in the first query `ST_DWithin` does the index supported proximity search, in the second query I used the [BBox KNN](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_box.html) operator `<#>` to sort by distance. Here, if you are confident that no line is further apart than a certain distance, you could include a `WHERE ST_DWithin(pt.geom, ln.geom, <distance>)` in the subquery to filter the points before sorting by distance).
If true ground distance is of concern to you, do a `geom::geography` cast and provide the threshold distance in meter instead of degree. If you do this, consider `ST_DWithin(pt.geom, ln.geom, <distance_in_meter>, false)` to let measures be made on a sphere instead of the spheroid; this should increase speed for the otherwise a little more time consuming *geography* distance measuerement.

Comment: as an addition to the second approach: the query needs around 6 seconds for 150k points and 350k lines on my mid-tech machine, and 4 with the `WHERE ...` filter; choose a distance so that you get each point returned in the result (fewer means the distance is too short). if you plan on inserting more points periodically, consider using a trigger to update those new points with their nearest line ids instead of running the query over and over. for updating lines however, you'd need to run it again.